# How to use FOSUserBundle with different users schema

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to use an existing users table with FOSUserBundle but I'm getting a weird error:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

My users table seems to be much different than that of FOSUserBundle.

The columns are:

```
id
name
email
password
salt
role
```

I think this is the problem because when I look at the log file I see an error like so:

> doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login AS last_login_8, t0.locked AS locked_9, t0.expired AS expired_10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at_11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_13, t0.roles AS roles_14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired_15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at_16, t0.id AS id_17...

And then:

> security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0):

My assumption is that it's because my schema doesn't have most of those columns.  So what can I do to rectify this?  Do I absolutely have to have those?

Comment: If you want to use FOSUserBundle as is, then, yes, I believe that you would need to implement those columns. However, you can implement a database user provider without using FOSUserBundle (or modify FOSUserBundle) to use whatever information you feel is relevant. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: @KalZekdor Thanks.  And how _should_ I go about adding those columns?

Comment: Depends on you are provisioning your database. You could edit the tables by hand using a tool such as Toad, Navicat, or MySQL Workbench. You might also want to look into Doctrine Migrations (http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html), which you can use to build database tables based on the Entity definitions (or vice versa).